# Rectify demand outstanding in India when tax was already paid

Tags: income-tax, india

I switched from one company to another company.
The old company deducted tax amt based on my income for that financial year.
But when I combined Form 16 of both the companies, I came to know that additional tax has to be paid. I paid the same while filing the returns. I am able to see the same paid details in 26AS form under PART C.
But now I got email from IT Department that I need to pay a demand outstanding amt with interest.

Can you any one pls help me how to prove it to IT Department so I need not pay the demand outstanding amt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does the 26AS show the TDS by both the companies to the extent you have claimed.

It depends on when the additional tax was paid. If you have paid it in April, then there will be "Interest" and "Penalty" charged on it.

The demand letter also shows the calculation's and the total tax. Is this same as what you had computed.

If you believe you have paid the tax, a print out of the form 26AS should be sufficient. This is going to be a long drawn activity and it would make sense if you speak to a CA.